# Why while(rs.next()) returning only last row data?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

In my code, while(rs.next()) is returning only the last row data. I have also tried using if(rs.next()) but it will give me only the data of the first row.

Please help me resolve this.

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
{ while(rs.next())
    {  System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getInt(8));

        l.setText(rs.getInt(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
        jb[0].setText(rs.getString(4));
        jb[1].setText(rs.getString(5));
        jb[2].setText(rs.getString(6));
        jb[3].setText(rs.getString(7));
        l.setVisible(true);
    }   
}   

l.setBounds(30,40,450,20);
for(int i=0,j=0;i<=90;i+=30,j++)
    jb[j].setBounds(50,80+i,200,20);
```

Comment: When you say `is returning only last row data` do you mean you are only printing the last row in your print statement, or that `l` and `jb` is only set to the last row?

Comment: You keep overwriting the values in `jb` with each iteration.  The last element in the `RS` is the last one written to `jb` - by the time you are using `jb` only the last element is left in it.

Comment: i need to use next(), because i want the next element in the iteration to be returned bt it keeps on showing the last row data everytime i click next

Comment: @ochi yeah m getting what you are saying but how to rectify this.? could you please help?

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado that's not the issue here, OP is not calling executeQuery inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep overwriting the values in `jb` with each iteration. The last element in the `RS` is the last one written to `jb` - by the time you are using `jb` only the last element is left in it.

I am not sure what you need to use the results for but you can use a 2D array of `Strings` to store all the values.  Something along the lines of:

***Updated based on comments, new understanding of question***

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    // stores the results into a collection
    List<JRadioButton[]> radioButtonList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<>();

    // iterate thru result set        
    while(rs.next()){
        // prints to console
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getInt(8));

        // init label
        JLabel l = new JLabel();
        l.setBounds(30,40,450,20);

        // set text for label
        l.setText(rs.getInt(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));

        // at least one element, set to visible
        l.setVisible(true);

        // store values from rs into an array of radio buttons
        JRadioButton[] jb = new JRadioButton[5];
        jb[0].setText(rs.getString(4));
        jb[1].setText(rs.getString(5));
        jb[2].setText(rs.getString(6));
        jb[3].setText(rs.getString(7));

        // store object in list for future use
        radioButtonList.add( jb );

        //store label in list
        labelList.add(l);
    }


    // now loop thru the lists
    for(JRadioButton[] jbArray : radioButtonList){
        // your code here - update to suit your needs
        // jbArray[4].setBounds(50,80,200,20); // not sure what the values should be here
    }

    for(JLabel jLabel: labelList){
        // your code here - update to suit your needs
        // jLabel.setBounds(50,80,200,20); // not sure what the values should be here            
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. here jb refers to the radiobuttons and the result i get is to be displayed as a question paper.

Comment: the string jbs u have defined is i guess jb.? n even if i do this it says setText(string) isn't defined for type string. Help plz.!

Comment: @p_S let me update the answer and see if I can help but since I don't know (you have not said) what is a `jb` nor how it is defined, I cannot give the exact solution.  Having said that, the answer is not about putting things into (and getting them out of) `jb` - it's about the ResultSet and iterating - which my code tries to address (and which is your original issue)

Comment: i want to address other issue in your code which i tried in my way.Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004688/whilers-next-statement-is-storing-the-data-to-a-2-d-array-but-still-the-arra

Comment: @p_S Yes but still are not telling what jb looks like... nobody can help you if you provide incomplete code...!

Comment: oops sry.. jb is basicallyvthe radiobutton array ,looks like--> JRadioButton jb[]=new JRadioButton[5];

Comment: @p_S And what are you trying to accomplish? - your issue was about a result set - which I answered - what is the purpose of the for loop after storing the values of the result set in JB?

Comment: What i am actually doing now is storing the data for JLabel l and JRadioButton jb[] in an array by iterating in the while(rs.next()) that's what you suggested.And now i want to display the data stored one by one, but still that's not happening and data of last row is only displayed by setText().help required again.:)

Comment: @p_S So, once you get a row from the result set and store into an array of JRadioButtons, you need to keep that array stored somewhere before the next row is processed (so now you have a list of radio button arrays) but only one label - how are they related?

Comment: No not one label, its a online exam type of code where i have made a single array for both label and radiobuttons, so i have a list of labels and radiobuttons corresponding to it stored in an array.

Comment: Ok, so that's not explained anywhere in your question and, actually, has nothing to do with the original question - which is iterating through the result set, which I answered

Comment: No its actually fully related to what you suggested, first of all while(rs.next()) wasn't working the way it should but your 2-D array idea has helped me alot.Thanx for that, now i am trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: @p_S see updated answer - it might be easier (than a 2D array) - let me know... gotta go now

Comment: Thank u very much for the effort, n I hv already upvoted your ans.But i joined stackoverflow community today itself, so my upvote i guess isn't visible publicly.But still thanx again, i'll try this one and let u know.